# Real-time replication of Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I'm still a Kubernetes newbie but I am already confronted with what I think is a mammoth task. My company is hosting a Kubernetes cluster. Because of internal policies, we are obliged to have everything georedundand. Which means we are supposed to build a second cluster (identical to the already existing one) in a different data center. Only ever one of them is active and the remaining one acts as a backup.

My task is to come up with different approaches on how we can synchronize those two clusters in real time, so that in case of failover operations can continue without much interruption.

From what I've heard such a replication can happen on different levels (hypervisor, storage, application...). I want to find out more about these different approaches but I lack the proper lingo to find any good online sources for my problem.
Do you guys know any sources who cover my question? Is there any literature on this? Or any personal experience you might want to share? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes is already a distributed system, by design.

It is more common to run a Kubernetes cluster by using **3** data centers - since it is built upon consensus algorithms like [raft](https://raft.github.io/). This replaces older ways to run systems by using **2** data centers in an [active-passive](https://www.jscape.com/blog/active-active-vs-active-passive-high-availability-cluster) fashion.